# How can I disable mobile data completely?

Tags: settings, mobile-data

I have a pre-paid plan and don't want to use my mobile data except for two days in the year. However, since there's the quick option button mobile data, I fear I might press the wrong button when I'm dizzy.

So is it possible to deactivate mobile data completely, such that a press on the "mobile data" quick button won't activate it anymore? Or a little bit more drastic: how can I remove that feature from my phone?

<sup>If the solution is device specific, I'm looking for an answer for a Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100, running stock 4.1.2), but I would like a general solution.</sup>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a dummy APN and select that as default.

With this, even if you enable data accidentally via toggles, it would still not connect.

<sup>PS: Added as an answer as suggested by OP</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To stop mobile data, delete the APN's (Access point names).

Long press on mobile data icon on your Android, this opens up the Mobile Networks settings screen. Check which APN's are there, you cannot delete them right away.

Just enter anything junk in all the fields. In MNC, put 000. Also, put 00 in everywhere else where it needs numeric. Now this APN should disappear.

Comment: That makes using the mobile data during the two mentioned days kind of hard, right? *"I [...] want to use my mobile data [...] for two days in the year."*

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the APNs on the phones mobile data settings would work. This way, it won't ever connect to mobile data through your carrier.

I discovered that after I tried installing apps that supposedly turn off or disable mobile data, but none of these work.

Comment: Google broke the ability for apps to turn mobile data on/off and (so far) are ignoring requests by developers to restore it. If this concerns you please feel free to comment on or star this bug, hopefully if enough people complain they will start listening: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78084

Answer (score 0):

Ask the service provider to stop the internet services so that they will stop it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Samsung smartphone will outsmart you. It will reinstall the default APN after system updating. Be careful, it will auto-connect to the mobile data when you change the SIM card, especially when the phone is new.

Answer (score -1):

Arrange your notification icons and move data to where it is inaccessible via quick buttons, then either create a new APN or delete existing APN and choose it as a default.

In my experience with Apple, the best option is deleting existing APNs, except for the MMS APN.

Comment: "In [your] experience with *Apple*"? You're aware that this is an Android specific question? Also, not every ROM has movable notification/quick settings.

Comment: -1: the answer is too generic. Possibly unrelated to Android.