# Disable mobile data permanently

Tags: internet, mobile-data, 4g

A strange request I know... but I am quite keen to disable mobile data from my phone permanently (as opposed to just switching it off in the settings) so that I can only browse the internet when I'm connected to Wifi.

I've tried getting my network provider (O2) to do this with my account but they said it's not possible.

Is it possible to achieve this in Android instead? I'm basically just looking for a way to 'break' it... whether that's by installing some kind of app then that would be fine (perhaps if I could then return it back to normal with a factory reset)

Comment: I don't think this is possible but you can do this by deleting​ the APN in Settings > Networks

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP has gone and existing answers have not been voted for more than 3 years). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete your APN settings on your phone's configuration, or use airplane mode.

Comment: thanks, I can reach the APN settings on my device, but can't see a way to remove them?

Comment: Enter to the APN you want to delete, and you'll see the three dots options menu on the top right corner. There should be an option to "Delete APN" there. You have to do that with every single one of them.

Comment: unfortunately I only see 'Reset to default' when I do that

Comment: Well, you could change the settings of the APNs with random wrong values so they don't actually connect...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure wether you can permanently disable data or not but you can always create a dummy APN and select that as default. With this, even if you enable data accidentally via toggles, it would still not connect. The best and sureshot way to stop mobile data is to delete the APN's (Access point names).

Check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64918/how-can-i-disable-mobile-data-completely) post from android enthusiast.

If you are rooted you can even consider using [droidWall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) like apps to prevent data access to apps

Answer (score 0):

You can get a custom recovery, then go to "wipe" section and there should be "EFS" Option. Wipe the EFS partion if you don't want mobile data.

Comment: Don't you think this would erase the IMEI number as well?