# Disabled mobile data but some data still transmitted

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mobile-data, background-data

I have expensive mobile data plan so I disabled mobile data in settings. But I still have a little amount of mobile data traffic every day that I paying for. (something near 100-1000 bytes, I inspected it in payment detalisation provided by operator)

I use home wifi for internet access so I need to disable only mobile data but not wifi.

I enabled `restrict background data` option but still have mobile traffic. [(screen1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZUKp.png)

In APN menu I can't delete/edit default APN supplied by mu operator. I created and selected fake APN as sugested in [How can I disable mobile data completely?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64918/how-can-i-disable-mobile-data-completely) but still have mobile traffic.

How can I (but not disable wifi)?

I suspect OS Android or Google services make this traffic. 
[(screen2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVO6t.png)

My phone is LG X style K200DS Android 6.0.1.

Comment: I assume you're using LTE? If so, try "locking" the device to UMTS (3G) and below. Without usage of mobile data, there's no advantage for LTE anyway.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for suggestion but where I can find this option?

Comment: Check in *Settings.* It's in a slightly different place with different ROMs, but there's a setting to chose the preferred network type.

Comment: @Izzy I found this menu and set GSM (2G) only. I will check whether it helps. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Cool. Let us know then!

Comment: @Izzy Unfontunately switching to GSM only doesn't helps. I still have small traffic

Comment: Sad. But was worth a try. I just remembered that recommendation for avoiding roaming costs (mentioned that LTE triggers small data packages even with mobile data off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install app like Glasswire and you can monitor your outgoing traffic. Or you can use firewall apps and try to disable the data on every app.

Comment: I definitely need some firewall (that works without root because I don't have one). I will search for it. Sorry, can't upvote this ansver due low reputation

Comment: @Yaros be welcome to take a look at [my list of Android firewall apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377). Has several candidates working without root. NetGuard is often recommended, being very flexible and covering a lot.

Comment: I installed "NoRoot Firewall" app and configured pre-filter on global rules tab. (filter for all ports, all ips, mobile network connection only) It works, I have no mobile traffic anymore.